# extract from json string oracle

Tags: sql, json, regex, oracle

I have JSON string in a column like below.
oracle version - 12c

```
{
[
{
"Employee_id": 1
,"Salary":3206.93
}
]
}
```

How do I remove first flower brace and the square bracket..

Result should look like below..

```
    {
    "Employee_id": 1
    ,"Salary":3206.93
    }
```

Tried using regex like `SELECT regexp_substr('"abc{[{def}]}ghi"', '\[(.+)\]') match FROM dual;`

But it didn't work..

Comment: You were close. REGEXP_SUBSTR needs an option if you want the "." to match carriage returns: regexp_substr(json_data_col, '\[(.*)\]', 1, 1, 'n') (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions138.htm)

Comment: Note that REGEXP_SUBSTR will include the square brackets in the result so you'd have to trim them.

Comment: you might look into [pljson](https://github.com/pljson/pljson) or similar library or tool

Answer (score 1):

```
select replace(replace(myColumn, '{[{', '{'), '}]}', '}')
from myTable
```

Note, this method will ONLY work if this column is always going to contain a single element of a JSON array, and if the JSON object doesn't contain any other JSON objects... otherwise it could break.  Use at your own risk :)